# Find a curve on $xy$-plane which passes through $(1, 1)$ and intersects all level curves of the function $f(x, y) = x^2e^y$ orthogonally.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Find an equation of the curve in the $xy$-plane which passes through $(1, 1)$ and which intersects all level curves of the function $f(x, y) = x^2e^y$ orthogonally.

---

I tried following this: [Level curves and intersections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569872/level-curves-and-intersections), but didn't lead me to the right solution.

$$\nabla f\cdot\nabla g = 2xe^y \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + x^2e^y\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2xe^y}$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{x^2e^y}$$

Which gives me the following curve.
$$g(x, y) = \frac{1}{2e^y}\ln{x} + \frac{1}{x^2e^y} + C$$

But this seems very wrong as the answer should be
$$4y=x^2+3.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something’s certainly gone wrong in your solving the differential eqaution since the $g$ that you computed doesn’t satisfy the orthogonality condition, but I think you went astray even before that. In the answer that you reference, the author chose to set $g_x$ and $g_y$ to (up to sign) reciprocals of $f_x$ and $f_y$ to satisfy the orthogonality constraint. That certainly gives you one set of solutions, but it’s certainly not the only one, and is not the easiest way to solve this problem.

Factor your orthogonality equation: $$2xe^yg_x+x^2e^yg_y = xe^y\left(2g_x+xg_y\right) = 0.$$ From this you have ${dy\over dx} = -{g_x\over g_y} = \frac x2$, which will lead you to the given solution. More generally, from the orthogonality condition $\nabla f\cdot\nabla g=0$ you can derive ${dy\over dx}={f_y\over f_x}$, turning the partial differential equation into an ordinary one.

Comment: Only thing I don't understand is how you arrived at ${dy\over dx} = -{g_x\over g_y} = \frac x2$. Or maybe, why does this hold ${dy\over dx}={f_y\over f_x}$?

Comment: @wednesdaymiko That’s implicit differentiation in action. If you have a function defined implicitly via an equation $g(x,y)=0$, then its derivative is equal to $-g_x/g_y$: the slope of the tangent is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the normal. The rest is just algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple curves that obey the requirement. You found one of them. The solution given uses
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=c$$
Then $$2xe^y\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+x^2e^y c=0$$
If $x\ne 0$, we can divide by $2xe^y$, to yield:
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-cx/2=0$$

Comment: Oh, so my answer is also correct after I've taken the point $(1, 1)$ into account, i.e. solved for $C$?

Comment: Note that you also have some errors in your calculation. If I take the partial derivatives of your $g(x,y)$, I do not get the original values you started with.

Comment: @wednesdaymiko  Those curves are unique due to the orthogonality condition

Answer (score 2):

Given the function $f(x,y) = x^2e^y$ the normal direction to the level curves is given by the gradient

$$
\nabla f = (2x e^y, x^2e^y)
$$

so the sought orbits obey

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f_y}{f_x} = \frac x2
$$

Solving we get

$$
y = \frac{x^2}{4}+ C_0
$$

so the sought orbit obeys $x = , y = 1 \rightarrow C_0 = \frac 34$

Attached a plot showing the path in red dashed.

[image]